# Calling Functions with Multiple Arguments when using Groupby

Tags: python, lambda, pandas

When writing functions to be used with groupby.apply or groupby.transform in pandas if the functions have multiple arguments, then when calling the function as part of groupby the arguments follow a comma rather than in parentheses. An example would be:

```
def Transfunc(df, arg1, arg2, arg2):
     return something

GroupedData.transform(Transfunc, arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Where the df argument is passed automatically as the first argument.

However, the same syntax does not seem to be possible when using a function to group the data. Take the following example:

```
people = DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 5), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], index=['Joe', 'Steve', 'Wes', 'Jim', 'Travis'])
people.ix[2:3, ['b', 'c']] = NA

def MeanPosition(Ind, df, Column):
    if df[Column][Ind] >= np.mean(df[Column]):
        return 'Greater Group'
    else:
        return 'Lesser Group'
# This function compares each data point in column 'a' to the mean of column 'a' and return a group name based on whether it is greater than or less than the mean

people.groupby(lambda x: MeanPosition(x, people, 'a')).mean()
```

The above works just fine, but I can't understand why I have to wrap the function in a lambda. Based upon the syntax used with transform and apply it seems to me that the following should work just fine:

```
people.groupby(MeanPosition, people, 'a').mean()
```

Can anyone tell me why, or how I can call the function without wrapping it in a lambda?

Thanks

EDIT: I do not think it is possible to group the data by passing a function as the key without wrapping that function in a lambda. One possible workaround is to rather than passing a function as the key, pass an array that has been created by a function. This would work in the following manner:

```
def MeanPositionList(df, Column):
    return ['Greater Group' if df[Column][row] >= np.mean(df[Column]) else 'Lesser Group' for row in df.index]

Grouped = people.groupby(np.array(MeanPositionList(people, 'a')))
Grouped.mean()
```

But then of course it could be better just to cut out the middle man function all together and simply use an array with list comprhension....

Comment: I think it's design decision, you can check sources and see, if it's possible (as far as I see, it's not) and if it's possible to add `**kwarg` to groupby in the future

Comment: Its frustrating! I mean wrapping it in a lambda is easy enough, but its hard to explain why this should be the case....

Answer (score 2):

Passing arguments to `apply` just happens to work, because `apply` passes on all arguments to the target function.

However, `groupby` takes multiple arguments, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html?highlight=groupby#pandas.DataFrame.groupby), so its not possible to differentiate between arguments; passing a lambda / named function is more explicit and the way to go.

Here is how to do what I think you want (slightly modified as you have all distinct groups in your example)

```
In [22]: def f(x):
   ....:     result = Series('Greater',index=x.index)
   ....:     result[x<x.mean()] = 'Lesser'
   ....:     return result
   ....: 

In [25]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 5), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], index=['Joe', 'Joe', 'Wes', 'Wes', 'Travis'])

In [26]: df
Out[26]: 
               a         b         c         d         e
Joe    -0.293926  1.006531  0.289749 -0.186993 -0.009843
Joe    -0.228721 -0.071503  0.293486  1.126972 -0.808444
Wes     0.022887 -1.813960  1.195457  0.216040  0.287745
Wes    -1.520738 -0.303487  0.484829  1.644879  1.253210
Travis -0.061281 -0.517140  0.504645 -1.844633  0.683103

In [27]: df.groupby(df.index.values).transform(f)
Out[27]: 
              a        b        c        d        e
Joe      Lesser  Greater   Lesser   Lesser  Greater
Joe     Greater   Lesser  Greater  Greater   Lesser
Travis  Greater  Greater  Greater  Greater  Greater
Wes     Greater   Lesser  Greater   Lesser   Lesser
Wes      Lesser  Greater   Lesser  Greater  Greater
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. That's what I assumed, but what I am wondering then, is how can I pass the above named function that has multiple arguments without the lambda notation. writing people.groupby(MeanPosition(people, 'a')) generates an error that says that insufficient arguments have been passed. How can I pass the Ind argument wihtout using the lambda notation? Or is it not possible?

Comment: I edited the answer. The grouper function is called on the index labels, so it only accepts 1 argument, in theory you could use a partial function. However, I believe the above solves your problem anyhow.

Comment: Thanks, actually that's not quite what I was looking for. I have edited my question. I don't think that I wanted to do can be achieved (i.e. call the group function without wrapping it in a lambda). One workaround is to pass a key to the group operation that is itself an array created by a function.