# Adjusting weights based on share prices for a investment portfolio using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, finance, trading

I have share prices for companies in a portfolio and my goal is to create new column `df['Final_weights']` yet keep the sum of weights for each date and category the same for `df['weights']` and `df['final_weights']`.

I want to give 0 to weights for companies which have a share price in the bottom 30 percentile for a particular day against companies in the same category, and I want to give higher weight to companies which have a share price over 70% percentile for a particular day against companies in the same category.

I have a dataframe with multiple dates and companies with respective category:

Eg subset of df:

```
 Date       Category    Company    Price    weight
1/1/2007    Automative  Audi        1000    0.146
1/1/2007    Automative  Alfa Romeo  400     0.143
1/1/2007    Automative  Aston Martin500     0.002
1/1/2007    Automative  Bentley     2000    0.025
1/1/2007    Automative  Mercedes    3000    0.063
1/1/2007    Automative  BMW          40     0.154
1/1/2007    Automative  Volvo       3000    0.163
1/1/2007    Automative  VW           200    0.003
1/1/2007    Technology  Apple        400    0.120
1/1/2007    Technology  Microsoft   5500    0.048
1/1/2007    Technology  Google       230    0.069
1/1/2007    Technology  Lenova        36    0.036
1/1/2007    Technology  IBM          250    0.016
1/1/2007    Technology  Sprint       231    0.013
```

OK now I have written some code which creates a new column giving the percentile rank of each company per date and per category. The code looks like this:

```
df['Pctile'] = df.Price.groupby([df.index, df.Category]).rank(pct='True')
```

Output:

```
            Category       Company  Price  weight    Pctile
Date                                                       
1/1/2007  Automative          Audi   1000   0.146  0.625000
1/1/2007  Automative    Alfa Romeo    400   0.143  0.375000
1/1/2007  Automative  Aston Martin    500   0.002  0.500000
1/1/2007  Automative       Bentley   2000   0.025  0.750000
1/1/2007  Automative      Mercedes   3000   0.063  0.937500
1/1/2007  Automative           BMW     40   0.154  0.125000
1/1/2007  Automative         Volvo   3000   0.163  0.937500
1/1/2007  Automative            VW    200   0.003  0.250000
1/1/2007  Technology         Apple    400   0.120  0.833333
1/1/2007  Technology     Microsoft   5500   0.048  1.000000
1/1/2007  Technology        Google    230   0.069  0.333333
1/1/2007  Technology        Lenova     36   0.036  0.166667
1/1/2007  Technology           IBM    250   0.016  0.666667
1/1/2007  Technology        Sprint    231   0.013  0.500000
```

Now I want a final column called `df['Final_weight']`.

All I want to do is for each date and category are these 3 things,

1. When `df['Pctile']` is `<0.3` I want `df['Final_weight'] = 0.`
2. When `df['Pctile']` is `>= 0.3` and `<= 0.7` then
   `df['Final_weight'] = df['weight']`.
3. When `df['PCtile'] >0.7` = `(weight / sum of weights above
   70%pctile) *(sum of weights above 70%pctile + sum of weights below
   30%pctile)`

Here is some sample output and example calculations:

- For Automative for `1/1/2007`:

1) `sum of weights above 70%pctile = 0.251`
2) `sum of weights below 30%pctile = 0.157`

Calculation for Bentley = `0.025 / 0.251 * (0.251 + 0.157) = 0.041`

Calculation for Mercedes = `0.063 / 0.251 * (0.251 + 0.157) = 0.102`

Calculation for Volvo = `0.163 / 0.251 * (0.251 + 0.157) = 0.265`

Now the sums of weight and final_weight for Automative for `1/1/2007` are the same. They both sum to 0.699.

- For Technology for `1/1/2007`:

1) `sum of weights above 70%pctile = 0.168`
2) `sum of weights below 30%pctile = 0.036`

Calculation for Apple = `0.120 / 0.168 * (0.168 + 0.036) = 0.146`

Calculation for Microsoft = `0.048 / 0.168 * (0.168 + 0.036) = 0.058`

Now the sums of weight and final_weight for Technology for `1/1/2007` are the same. They both sum to 0.302. Also the sum of that date also remains 1.

Eg output:

```
            Category       Company  Price  weight    Pctile  Final_weight
Date                                                       
1/1/2007  Automative          Audi   1000   0.146  0.625000  0.146
1/1/2007  Automative    Alfa Romeo    400   0.143  0.375000  0.143
1/1/2007  Automative  Aston Martin    500   0.002  0.500000  0.002
1/1/2007  Automative       Bentley   2000   0.025  0.750000  0.041
1/1/2007  Automative      Mercedes   3000   0.063  0.937500  0.102
1/1/2007  Automative           BMW     40   0.154  0.125000  0.000
1/1/2007  Automative         Volvo   3000   0.163  0.937500  0.265
1/1/2007  Automative            VW    200   0.003  0.250000  0
1/1/2007  Technology         Apple    400   0.120  0.833333  0.146
1/1/2007  Technology     Microsoft   5500   0.048  1.000000  0.058
1/1/2007  Technology        Google    230   0.069  0.333333  0.069
1/1/2007  Technology        Lenova     36   0.036  0.166667  0.000
1/1/2007  Technology           IBM    250   0.016  0.666667  0.016
1/1/2007  Technology        Sprint    231   0.013  0.500000  0.013
```

My data is large, with many categories, dates, companies. Would love to see an efficient way of programming this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I wish this was a groupby-of-a-groupby solution it isn't. It is a bit of a dirty hack. The reason I could not do the groupby solution is because, as far as I am aware, there is no way of selecting and passing columns into [multiple argument functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761140/calling-functions-with-multiple-arguments-when-using-groupby) with a groupby. Enough of what cannot be done...

Now I said it was hacky so give it a go on your data set. I dont know how fast it is on a large data set but do let me know.

```
import pandas as pd

#make a lazy example
date = ['1/1/2017']*10
category = ['car']*5 + ['tech']*5
company = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
price = [10, 300, 100, 400, 500, 230, 324, 543, 234, 124]
weight = [0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.15, 0.15, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2]

data = {'date': date, 'category': category, 'company': company, 'price': price, 'weight': weight}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#do you percentile thing
df['pctile'] = df.price.groupby([df.date, df.category]).rank(pct='True')

# define a function?
def seventy_thirty(df):
    s = df.ix[df.pctile > 0.7, 'pctile']
    s.ix[:] = 'upper'
    l = df.ix[df.pctile < 0.3, 'pctile']
    l.ix[:] = 'lower'
    s = s.append(l)
    return s

df['pctile_summary'] = seventy_thirty(df)

# created a dataframe with weights the we can merge make into another column
weighted = df.groupby(['date', 'category', 'pctile_summary']).sum().ix[:, ['weight']]

# add lowers onto uppers as we'll need them in final_weights
add_lower = weighted.ix[weighted.index.get_level_values('pctile_summary')=='lower', ['weight']].reset_index(level=2)
add_lower.pctile_summary = 'upper'
add_lower = add_lower.set_index('pctile_summary', append=True)
weighted = pd.merge(weighted, add_lower, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=['', '_lower'])

# Now add all new columns and calculate the final_weight
df1 = pd.merge(df, weighted.reset_index(), how='left', on=['date', 'category', 'pctile_summary'], suffixes=['', '_sum'])
df1.ix[df1.pctile_summary=='lower', 'final_weight'] = 0
df1.ix[df1.pctile_summary.isnull(), 'final_weight'] = df1.weight
df1.ix[df1.pctile_summary=='upper', 'final_weight'] = (df1.weight / df1.weight_sum) * (df1.weight_sum + df1.weight_lower)

#finally tidy up (delete all that hardwork!)
df1 = df1.drop(['pctile_summary', 'weight_sum', 'weight_lower'], axis=1)
df1
```

Comment: it's late here so hopefully I can add to this tomorrow

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes please do, I was not able to run on larger real data because it takes too long. Thanks again.

Comment: how big is the set?

Comment: 800k rows with 25 odd columns.

Comment: Also maybe my percent rank within date and categories is not behaving as it should be but should not effect the output results. Thanks